# How to change wordpress domain name when site has asp.login page for portal in a separate directory?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess, web-config, subdomain

My client wants to change his Wordpress site's domain name (from info.safetyalert.com 
to safetyalert.com).

On the server there are two directories: info.safetyalert.com 
(where the user is redirected when they type www.safetyalert.com into browser) and
safetyalert.com, which contains the old site which is not rendered with the exception of a login.asp page for customers that directs them to a "non-Wordpress" portal for submitting reports which is in turn linked to a database (you can see the Login link at the upper right hand corner when accessing the Wordpress home page).

My question is: In which files would I need to edit to make safetyalert.com permanent (and not changing to info.safetyalert.com in the address bar) when users goto the Wordpress site, but without affecting/crashing the login.asp page and the database in the other directory?

My previous attempts have resulted in a loop.  I can provide additional info if needed.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

login to admin panel of http://info.safetyalert.com/, and go to Settings > General, then change the URL (ie from http://info.safetyalert.com/ to http://www.safetyalert.com ), then you problem is solved.